# How to configure and enable NAT with server core installation

Tags: routing, powershell, windows-server-2012, nat, windows-server-core

Using Microsoft Server 2012 Core:

What is the equivalent core/Powershell command to enable and configure NAT. I have configured NAT on servers with the following GUI steps:

Server Manager, Tools, Routing and Remote Access, Right click on machine, "Configure and Enable Routing and Remote Access"

Select "Network address translation (NAT)" radio box,

Pick public interface.

I found "Install-RemoteAccess" but I'm stuck on the prompting for ConnectToAddress. It needs to be public or something but the GUI does not seem to have this requirement.

Thanks,
Kevin

Repost from http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/b1b35cf2-f9bb-4a74-8d6d-73a0044d4799/how-to-configure-and-enable-nat-with-server-core-installation

Comment: God speed. That sounds difficult. I'd be using the MMC snapin on another machine to remotely administer the RRAS server.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I have been doing. The goal is to fully automate installation/configuration of certain services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't all that pretty, but take a look at this: https://windowsmasher.wordpress.com/2013/03/02/scripting-the-build-of-a-server-2008-r2-test-domain/ After this either call "Start-Service RemoteAccess" or "net start remote access". This script assumes the public interface is named "Public Interface" and the private interface is named "Private Network".

Answer (score 1):

The PowerShell [Network Address Translation (NAT) Cmdlets](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn283352.aspx) are only available in Server 2012 R2, even using PowerShell 4 or copying the NetNat module does not help. So you're stuck with the netsh commands.